# Duda Symfony, Ajax, Controlador

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony2

¿Cómo puedo hacer lo que se plantea en [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078834/symfony-ajax-controller-handler-always-fires-jquery-error-function) pregunta, pero pasándole un parámetro al controlador desde el ajax, y luego, desde el controlador devolverle a la misma vista donde se ejecuta el ajax dicho parámetro a través de twig?

Esto puede sonar redundante pero lo hago para obtener en la vista una variable twig que su valor es desconocido y me llega a través de una variable javascript en la misma vista. Igual, si conocen otra forma de hacerlo sin tener que hacer todo lo anterior, me dicen. Gracias.

Comment: No sería más recomendable ejecutar una acción por AJAX y pasarle parámetros al controlador y luego, al retorno, adjuntar vía javascript/jquery? ($('#id).append(response) o $('#id).html(response))

Comment: Creo que a través de Twig no puedes. Twig se utiliza al renderizar por primera vez una página pero no puedes interactuar con él mediante javascript de manera nativa. Existe alguna librería como esta => https://github.com/schmittjoh/twig.js que emularía quizá el uso de Twig en js.

Answer (score 1):

Si esa variable no la vas a modificar en el controlador y lo que quieres es modificar el DOM es más recomendable que hagas esa modificación con el mismo Javascript así no pierdes tiempo con la petición. Además, cuando regrese la petición no hay manera de pasarle el valor a Twig porque ya la página está compilada.